# OpenCV - Creating Bounding boxes and circles for contours - Xcode [Objective-C++]

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, eye-detection

a similar question like mine was already posted, but there is still some part which doesn't fit to my current problem. I use Xcode
and Objective C++ to work with openCV.

What I do want to do is to create some bounding boxes and circles around human eyes in photos. I have used the following code but this does not work:

```
-(void)detectEye {

cv::Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
RNG rng(12345);

NSString *path = @"/Users/NazarMedeiros/Desktop/image.jpg";

cv::Mat src = cv::imread("/Users/NazarMedeiros/Downloads/face.jpg");
if (src.empty())
    return;

cv::cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
cv::blur(src_gray, src_gray, cv::Size(3,3) );

cv::Mat threshold_output;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

/// Detect edges using Threshold
cv::threshold( src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
/// Find contours
cv::findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

/// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
std::vector<cv::Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
std::vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
std::vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
    cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
    boundRect[i] = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
    cv::minEnclosingCircle( (cv::Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
}

/// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
    cv::Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
    cv::drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, std::vector<Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point() );
    cv::circle( drawing, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0 );
}
imwrite([path UTF8String], src);}
```

}
The imwrite-function does not save my image..

Can anyone help me, please?
Best regards,
Nazar Medeiros

Comment: Try to change the cv::Mat img;  UIImage * image = MatToUIImage(img);

Answer (score 2):

Try convert "drawing" to UIImage

```
- (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                 //width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                 //height
                                        8,                                          //bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                       //bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                            //bytesPerRow
                                        colorSpace,                                 //colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
                                        provider,                                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                       //decode
                                        false,                                      //should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   //intent
                                        );


    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return finalImage;
}
```